# Halve a number in a single line

Tags: python, list-comprehension

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
l = []
n = 100
while (n):
    l.append(n//2)
    n //= 2
    
print(l)
# [50, 25, 12, 6, 3, 1, 0]
```

What I've tried:

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> n = 100
>>> [(n := n//2) for _ in takewhile(lambda x: x > 0, [n] * n)]
[50, 25, 12, 6, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ... 0, 0, 0]
```

This clearly doesn't work, and I also don't like the idea of creating an array of size `n`...

Comment: As always with questions asking for one-liners - ***why***? While the answer by Manby works, it is much harder to grasp and understand at a glance then your conventional loop

Comment: @Tomerikoo because the hw assignment said so ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from math import log2, floor
n = 100
l = [n//(2**x) for x in range(1, floor(log2(n))+2)]
```

This will leave `l` as `[50, 25, 12, 6, 3, 1, 0]`.
If you don't want the 0, change the `+2` to `+1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `numpy` to get vectorized solution:

```py
import numpy as np

n= 100

arr = np.array(n * np.ones(int(np.log(n)/np.log(2))))

arr = np.floor(arr / 2**(np.arange(len(arr)) + 1))
```

Outputs:

```py
[50. 25. 12.  6.  3.  1.]
```

Brief explanation:

1. Size of array you're looking for is: `log_2(n)`, which I calculate from: `int(np.log(n)/np.log(2))` which in essence returns highest integer exponent satisfying the inequality: `2^x <  n`
2. Then you can just restate the problem as `sum[i=1 to x](n//2^i)`